# Prevent addition of span tag

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

I have the following markup in a template:

```
<p class="form-action-title"><i class="icon-edit"></i> {{t generic.title.edit}} ...</p>
```

And this is rendered as:

```
<p class="form-action-title"><i class="icon-edit"></i> <span id="i18n-14">Editar</span> ...</p>
```

I would like to completely remove the `<span>` for the translated text (it messes-up my styling). I have tried with:

```
{{t generic.title.edit tagName=""}}
```

But has no effect. The strange thing is that, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n#translate-attributes-in-a-view), the following `{{t}}`:

```
{{#view Em.Button titleTranslation="button.add_user.title">
  {{t button.add_user.text}}
{{/view}}
```

Renders no `<span>`:

```
<button title="Add a user">
  Add
</button>
```

(I haven't tried this, I just trust the docs)

What can I do to get rid of the `<span>`?

Comment: Guess there is no way to get rid of span in `t` helper as you could see here https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.js#L170

Comment: @Selva-G: Strange anyway that, according to the documentation, `{{t button.add_user.text}}` renders `Add`, without `<span>`. Maybe because it is within a `<button>` tag? But my `{{t}}` is also within a `<p>`, so no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two options:**

Patch the source: https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.js#L133 and https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.js#L170

Or create your own simple helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n', function(key) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(Ember.I18n.t(key))
});
```

and then

```
{{i18n generic.title.edit}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I had to do `Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n', function(key) {` instead of the `Ember.Handlebars.helper`. I have had this issue before, not sure what it is. They work slightly differently. Anyway, with `Handlebars.registerHelper` works perfectly!

Comment: @gonvaled, the difference beetwen `registerHelper` and `helper` is that `registerHelper` is binding un-aware, but if your tranlateable keys are static and don't change while your app is running then `registerHelper` is fine.